# Compute the expected size of an approximation of vertex cover

Tags: graphs, approximation, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, vertex-cover

Consider the following randomized approximation algorithm of vertex cover:

- Input: A graph G = (V, E).
- Output: A set $C_G \subseteq V$ a vertex cover of $G$.

The algorithm:

1. Set $C_G := \emptyset$.
2. For each edge $e$, in some arbitrary order:

   3. If $e$ is covered, skip it and continue to the next iteration of the loop.
   4. Let $e=\{u,v\}$.  Choose an endpoint $w \in \{u, v\}$ uniformly at random.
   5. Add $w$ to $C_G$.

Let $C_G$ be the solution computed by this algorithm for a given graph $G$, and $\operatorname{OPT}_G$ an optimal solution. I found a proof (see [link](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/cs4234/lectures/01.VertexCover.pdf)), that $$\mathbb{E}[|C_G|] \leq 2 \mathbb{E}[|\operatorname{OPT}_G|].$$

I have been trying however, to find a way to compute $\mathbb{E}[|C_G|]$ for a given graph $G = (V, E)$. The best I could come up with, is a dynamic programming solution over all subsets of the vertices, i.e. for each $S \subseteq 2^V$, we have to computed $C_{G[S]}$. This solution has $O^*(2^n)$ space and time complexity.

Is it possible to compute the expected value of $|C_G|$ in polynomial time or is it possible to prove that it is NP-hard to compute $\mathbb{E}[|C_G|]$?

Comment: Just a quick note that the proof you linked to has a technical error (a gap).  See comments on https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119065/derandomization-of-vertex-cover-algorithm?rq=1 for more details.

Comment: One possible approach: numerical precision.  Show that (for arbitrarily large n) there is a graph with n vertices where the expectation requires exponentially many bits to represent exactly.

Comment: @NealYoung thanks, this seems to answer my question. I was wondering however, about the question in this link. It seems that a machine that outputs the expectation rounded up to the next integer suffices for this specific case
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119065/derandomization-of-vertex-cover-algorithm

Comment: That's an interesting observation.  Note: I don't know whether the suggestion in my other comment works or not, it was just a possible line of attack.